# How Can I Record Text-To-Speech Output

Tags: text-to-speech

Android has a Text-To-Speech engine called **PicoTTS**.

Is there any way to have it read a file and **save the output to an audio file** (instead of routing the audio to the headset or speakers) without programming a custom app myself?

---

**UPDATE:** The OS has a [synthesizeToFile()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#synthesizeToFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.HashMap%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%3E,%20java.lang.String%29) method ... I'm just looking for an app that uses it instead of developing one on my own.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your default Text-to-Speech engine is PicoTTS (from settings). Install and start a sound recording app (there are many in Play Store). Send it to background and use [Speaking Pad](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ideal.speakingpad).